# What listener should I choose to make the view listen to the model when using MVC? (java)

Tags: java, model-view-controller, view, model, listener

In a MVC-project, I want the view to listen to the model. So when ever something is changed in the model I want to notify the view, triggering it to update itself accordingly. Previously I've used observer/observable for this type of situation but since they are deprecated I'd like to learn how to use listeners for this. What would be the equivalent to having an object in the model implement Observable and a view object be an observer of that? I've used java's EventListeners for listening to GUI components but are there any listeners specifically intended to listen to the model? Are there any good articles with information on how to choose listener?

Thank you!!

Comment: Could you provide some context? What kind of "view" are you working with? Are you building a web app? Desktop app?

Comment: Well its not really about this specific case, rather for the general MVC pattern. However, this time it will be a desktop app :)

Answer (score 0):

Java Event's library is made so it can be used for any purpose. They are widely used in Swing to handle GUI events, however, they can be used in any other context.

To be honest, if you really need a specific solution you could always implement your own listener, it is not that hard.

If your model follows the [JavaBeans](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html) standard, I will suggest using a [PropertyChangeListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html). That way you can track any change made to it.